# How to have MATLAB display answer in decimals with e instead of fractions

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

So im using MATLAB to calculate the coefficient of an equation and it keeps displaying fractions as the constants instead of decimal form like xxe-x
My code is below

```
bt = 0.03175;
bpzt = 0.0078;
ht = 0.003;
w = 50; % frequency in Hz
pnic = 8908; % density of nickel
Enic = 200e9; % Young's modulus of nic
L = 0.3048; % Length of canitlever beam in m

syms hn

inertia = (1/12)*bt*ht^3 + (1/2)*bpzt*ht^2*hn - (1/2)*bpzt*ht*hn^2 + (2/3)*bpzt*hn^3

area = (bt*ht - 2*hn*bt + 2*bpzt*hn);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the symbolic math toolbox. You have to convert any symbolic variable back to a numerical one. Use `double(area)` to get a double value of your symbolic variable `area`. You can use the function `single`, too.
But be aware that `hn` has to get a value first, otherwise it cannot be determined.

Documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html

To format this output, use the usual Matlab tools. In your case `format short e`

More details: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-format-for-numeric-values.html

Comment: I keep getting an error that says  error in mupadmex when using double or single and suggests i use VPA. When i do use vpa it works in showing me the decimal but then decimals are not formatted nicely like i would get a 0.0000000000000001 instead i want something like 1e-9

Comment: @usr1234567: Conversion to double is not possible because `area` has a unknown `hn`

Answer (score 1):

In R2014b, this line:

```
inertia = (1/12)*bt*ht^3 + (1/2)*bpzt*ht^2*hn - (1/2)*bpzt*ht*hn^2 + (2/3)*bpzt*hn^3
```

returns

```
(13*hn^3)/2500 - (863307622649607*hn^2)/73786976294838206464 + (5304162033559185*hn)/151115727451828646838272 + 5527208847278085/77371252455336267181195264
```

which is a symbolic expression with numeric values represented exactly as rational fractions (even though they may have started out as decimal values in your code). You can convert this using [`vpa`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html)

```
vpa(inertia)
```

which returns:

```
0.0052*hn^3 - 0.000011699999999999999788190263583232*hn^2 + 0.000000035099999999999996664653271376613*hn + 0.000000000071437500000000005341045287673881
```

The length/precision of the decimal values depends on [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html). Displaying this in an exponential-style format (xxe-x) is not an option for any symbolic math expression or value unless you write your own function to parse the string and do the conversion.

To convert this to a vectorized double-precision floating point function, you can use the terribly-named [`matlabFunction`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html) – `matlabFunction(inertia)` returns:

```
@(hn)hn.*3.51e-8-hn.^2.*1.17e-5+hn.^3.*5.2e-3+7.143750000000001e-11
```

But if you're doing this, I'd wonder why you were working with symbolic math in the first place and if it's possible to do everything in much faster double precision.

Keep in mind that if you want to convert to any kind of decimal form, variable precision or floating-point, in many cases you *will* lose precision. However, if you just want to view the result or perform fourth calculations if double precision, then it should be fine.