# Matlab series evaluation gives weird result

Tags: matlab

I try to evaluate the following series in Matlab

> S2 = symsum((1/(n^2)),n,1,Inf)

and it gives me the result directly which is `pi^2/6`
However, when I tried to do something like this

> S3 = (pi^2)/S2

it gives me something that looks like this

> 8334140006820045/(140737488355328*pi^2)

which is weird in my opinion. I know that I can just put the value of **S2** directly but I'm just wondering why this is happening. Can someone help me out? Btw, I'm just beginner in using Matlab.

Comment: To have the result in decimal, use:  `eval` (sym/eval) or `double` (but that uses the other eval) or `vpa`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! @SardarUsama

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to have MATLAB display answer in decimals with e instead of fractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803672/how-to-have-matlab-display-answer-in-decimals-with-e-instead-of-fractions)

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a double first then evaluate.

```
syms k
S1 = symsum(1/k^2, k, 1, Inf)
format long
S3 = double(S1);
S2 = pi^2/S3
```

S2 =

```
 6
```